# whenever gem issues using runner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, whenever, runner

Controller:

```
    class CronjobsController < ApplicationController
      def just_check
        meeting_id = 1
        UserMailer.upcoming_meeting_email_twelve_hours_before(meeting_id).deliver
      end
    end
```

Model:

```
    class Cronjob < ActiveRecord::Base
      def self.just_check
        meeting_id = "meeting.id"
        UserMailer.upcoming_meeting_email_twelve_hours_before(meeting_id).deliver
      end
    end
```

schedule.rb

```
    every 2.minute do
      runner "Cronjob.just_check", :environment => "development"
    end
```

But the issue is that after every **2 minutes** runner is not able to call the models method.

Comment: may be cronjobs have some issue with rvm but how to resolve that issue

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated the **crontab** with the jobs in **schedule.rb** file.

Update the crontab with the following command

```
whenever --update-crontab --set environment=development
```

If you updated properly, then can u please past the jobs of crontab.

You can get the crontab jobs by **crontab -l**. And also check the log file for any error messages.

Comment: that could be a comment =)

Comment: Yes, but i don't know i am not able to add the comments over there :(.